# Echo a table in PHP array looping

Tags: php, arrays

so I have this array

```
array (size=17)
'id' => string '21' (length=2)
'request_area' => string 'Area 1' (length=6)
'ship_product_code' => string '795919' (length=6)
'ship_product_description' => string 'BULBs' (length=5)
'qty' => string '2.0000' (length=6) 

 array (size=17)
'id' => string '22' (length=2)
'request_area' => string 'Area 1' (length=6)
'ship_product_code' => string '123' (length=3)
'ship_product_description' => string '321s' (length=4)
'qty' => string '3.0000' (length=6)
```

those arrays are inside

```
$product
```

I loop the product array and echo a table using following code

```
if(count($product)>0){
            $i=0;
            foreach($product as $v){
                $i++;
                $CONTENT.= '
                    <tr> 
                        <td align="center" width="7%"> </td>
                        <td align="center" width="50%">'.$v['request_area'].'</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" width="7%">'.$i.'</td>
                        <td align="center" width="50%">'.$v['ship_product_description'].'</td>
                        <td align="center" width="7%">'.number_format($v['qty']).'</td>
                        <td width="7%"> </td>
                    </tr>
                ';
            }
        }
```

The problem from above code is, it will create a tr with

```
 Request Area
 Item 1
 Request Area
 Item 2
```

What I want is, it prints the request area only once, and then followed by the Items. How can I achieve it?

```
 Request Area //only once
 Item 1
 Item 2
 Item 3 
 // and so on
```

Thank you :)

Comment: it would be helpful to have the code for the arrays (the 2 upper arrays look like they could be json)

Comment: the $product array is a query result from the database sir :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your question if you try the following it will give you your desired results:

```
   if(count($product)>0){
        $i=0;
        foreach($product as $v){
            if($i == 0){
                $CONTENT .= '<tr> 
                    <td align="center" width="7%"> </td>
                    <td align="center" width="50%">'.$v['request_area'].'</td>
                </tr>';
            }
            $i++;
            $CONTENT.= '

                <tr>
                    <td align="center" width="7%">'.$i.'</td>
                    <td align="center" width="50%">'.$v['ship_product_description'].'</td>
                    <td align="center" width="7%">'.number_format($v['qty']).'</td>
                    <td width="7%"> </td>
                </tr>
            ';
        }
    }
```

Comment: this is really a great "hack" ! you are awesome Sir! wonder why I can't think of such way. thank you!